# Can I add links to my Google Chrome history without opening the URLs?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, history

I'm the only person on Earth who wants to ADD items to their browser history, but I ask because part of my job is compiling and reviewing lists of links, and it's easier if I have the links in my browser history and can see which links have already been opened to validate that they're already on my list. Opening up 300 URLs at once with an extension is an easy way to melt Chrome down. Any way to add a batch list of links to my browser history?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this link](https://www.foxtonforensics.com/browser-history-examiner/chrome-history-location) for some detailed info on how Chrome stores browser history.

If you're handy with scripting SQLite data imports, you could potentially automate that fairly easily by loading the URLs into the history file. I took a look myself and it's an extensionless file but it opens in SQLite database browsers as any normal .db file would.